# how to set price filter in magento custom grid

Tags: magento-1.9

How to filter the price in custom grid with exact result. if I give 500 it displays the digit relevant to 500 like 5000,7500 like, how could i avoid this

```
$this->addColumn("price", array( "header" => 
Mage::helper("dashboarddlr")->__("Price"), "index" => "price",
'width' => '150px', 'type' => 'currency','currency'=>'order_currency_code', 
//'filter_index'=>'main_table.price', 
"renderer" => new Vignesh_DashboardDealer_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Price(), ));
```

Comment: are you need in admin side grid?

Comment: Please share or else question goes to closed

Comment: Yes i already use 'filter_index'=>'main_table.price'

Comment: Plase show ur code

Comment: $this->addColumn("price", array(
    "header" => Mage::helper("dashboarddlr")->__("Price"),
    "index" => "price",
    'width'    => '150px',
    'type'      => 'currency',
    'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    //'filter_index'=>'main_table.price',
          "renderer" => new Vignesh_DashboardDealer_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Price(),
    
    ));  in renderer i just return float point.

Comment: PLease put ,ur complete code at question ... Not on comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->addColumn('your_field_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('your_field_lable'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'index' => 'your_field_name',
       ));
```

**OR**

```
 $this->addColumn('your_field_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('your_field_lable'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => 'your_field_name',
        ));
```

Comment: sorry i really new to this too.

Comment: can you share you setCollection Function (grid.php)